# PouchDB on Put method will return "Document update conflict"

Tags: pouchdb

PouchDB cannot update the CouchDB entries.
It gives back "Document update conflict."

I read the conflict problem on pouchdb documnetation, I tried a lot of scenario, but always the same result.
`409 Document update conflict`

So here the last one code:

```
docs.forEach((element, index) => {
              if (categoriesData[element._id] != null){
                pouchdatabase.get(element._id).then(function (origDoc) {
                  // var doc = element;
                  // doc._rev = origDoc._rev;
                  // doc.name = categoriesData[element._id].newName;

                  // var doc = {
                  //   _id: element._id,
                  //   _rev: origDoc._rev,
                  //   name: categoriesData[element._id].newName
                  // };

                  pouchdatabase.put( {
                    _id: element._id,
                    _rev: origDoc._rev,
                    name: categoriesData[element._id].newName
                  }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log('updated');
                  }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  });
                });
              }
            });
```

I tried with this solution (found on Pouchdb github), but the same error...

```
var retryUntilWritten = function (doc) {
              return pouchdatabase.get(doc._id).then(function (origDoc) {
                doc._rev = origDoc._rev;
                return pouchdatabase.put(doc);
              }).catch(function (err) {
                if (err.status === 409) {
                  return retryUntilWritten(doc);
                } else { // new doc
                  return pouchdatabase.put(doc);
                }
              });
            };
```

Do you have any idea how can I update the `name` of the category?

Locally the name attribute will be replaced! (in pouchdb, but not will updated to the couchdb!)

Answer (score 5):

Conflicting happen when you try to update a document without _rev or the revision of your documents outdated (deleted from revision tree).

So, to update without a valid _rev. You can set options `force` equal `true`

`const respond = await db.put(doc, {force: true})`

read more about conflict [here](https://pouchdb.com/guides/conflicts.html):

> Note:  to limited conflicting, limited change your document by small pieces